# Python List Out of Bounds Error - OpenPyXL

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, openpyxl

> Hello. I'm currently experiencing an error in my logic and I'm stumped. Could someone please take a look? I'm getting an list out of bounds error. The first list is a list of string. The second list is a list of list.

**I also have values in both lists despite not showing in code.**

```
uniqueFileNameCollection = []

uniqueManagerReviewCollection = []

 j = 0

    for i in range(0, len(uniqueFileNameCollection)):

        for cell in results_manager_sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=len(uniqueFileNameCollection), min_row=2, max_row=len(uniqueManagerReviewCollection[i]) + 1):

            if j == len(uniqueManagerReviewCollection[i]):

                j = 0

            print(cell[i].coordinate)

            cell[i].value = str(uniqueManagerReviewCollection[i][j])

            j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i in range(0, len(uniqueFileNameCollection)):
    for j in range(0, len(uniqueManagerReviewCollection[i])):
        results_manager_sheet.cell(
            row=j+2, column=i+1).value = uniqueManagerReviewCollection[i][j]
```